# Android - specifying layout_width when using layout_weight

Tags: android, android-layout-weight

When I am specifying a `weight` between say and `image view` and a `linear layout` which are contained within the same `linear layout` what should I be setting the `layout_width` values to? It seems like it shouldnt be set because I am saying I want the other `layout` to take up 90% of space and the `image view` to take 10% of space.

Also it seems like I can set the `image view` to have 10% space and the `layout` to have 90% space but I can still specify a value in `dp's` for the `image view`?

In this instance should I just set the value in `dp's` on the `image` and then specify a `weight` of `1` for the other `layout`?

Thanks

Comment: please post that you've tried so far.

Comment: Well Ive tried a few different things and they look ok in the emulator, so I am asking really what is the correct thign to specify for layout_width when using weights and also if it is ok to use a layout_weight and then set the layout_width value in dp's?

Comment: Set the width to 0dp.

Comment: Thanks thats what I was looking for, and for the other question, if I have a width of 150dp for an image view do I set the weight for the other contained view to 1 or just leave it to match_parent?

Comment: try to set android:layout_width="0px"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case your layout_width should be `0dp`. you will also get a lint warning if will define width other than `0dp` with a weight param.

[refer this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html) for more details.

Comment: ok thanks Rahul, could you just update to say whether I should use  a layout weight when specifying an image has a width of 150dp, should the other view contained specify its weigth as 1, fill rest of space or should it be match_parent?

Comment: [refer this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html) for details. after reading it you will know how weights work.

Answer (score 1):

When using weight in layout.
you will want to do this.

The parent layout will have a `weightSum=10` using a value of 10, but it could be any value we want. 
for the children layout. all should be`layout_width="fill_parent"`then you can then set the `layout_weight="2"` for one of the child and then `layout_weight="8"` for the other child

something like this

```
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="10">


<imageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="8"
    />

<LinearLayoout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2" />
```